# powershell autologin webapplication

Tags: html, powershell

My problem is a computer which automatically logs into an infopanel web application. Everything goes as scripted until the credentials should be submitted - web application starts in browser, username and password are filled in, but are not submitted - handed over to the application by pushing a login button.

I have put part of the login source code of the web application below:

```
<div class="editor-submit">
<input class="k-button" type="submit" value="Login" />
</div>
```

The powershell script to process the autologin is as follows:

```
$Url = “http://crm-mobile:8080/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f”
$Username=”xxx”
$Password=”yyy”
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$IE.visible = $true;
$IE.navigate($url);

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)
{
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;
}
$IE.Document.getElementById(“Username”).value = $Username
$IE.Document.getElementById(“Password”).value = $Password
$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("k-button") |
? { S_.Type -eq 'submit' -and S_.value -eq "Login" } |
% { S_.Click() }
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)
{
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;
}
```

Could somebody please help me out in finding a working solution to this autologin problem? Many thanx in advance,

Kind regards,

Richard

Comment: Can you try to put `$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("k-button") |
? { S_.Type -eq 'submit' -and $_.value -eq "Login" }` in a variable and check whether its not null?

Comment: When modifying the script in it's simplest form, the webpage is at least opening and auto-filling in the username and password. However the button is not pushed to hand over the credentials to the web application. How can I identify the Login-button? The username and password elements have both an ID in the source code.

Comment: $Url = “http://crm-mobile:8080/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f”
    $Username=”xxx”
    $Password=”yyy”
    $IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
    $IE.visible = $true;
    $IE.navigate($url);
    while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)

    {

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;

    }

   $IE.Document.getElementById(“Username”).value = $Username
   $IE.Document.getElementById(“Password”).value = $Password
   $IE.Document.getElementById(“submit”).Click();
   while ($IE.Busy -eq $true)

   {

   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000;

}

Comment: can you answer my question?